# Swift 4.1 - Set extension requires Element to conform to Encodable

Tags: swift, generics, set, codable, swift4.1

```
protocol CodableWithDefault: Codable {
    static var `default`: Self { get }
}

extension Set: CodableWithDefault {
    static var `default`: Set {
        return Set()
    }
}
```

This was working fine in Swift 4, but since 4.1 it complains:

`'CodableWithDefault' requires that 'Element' conform to 'Encodable'`

I could not find any way to express that I want to have an extension of `Set` that is constrained to `Element` also implement `Encodable`.

Is this at all possible with Swift 4.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this

```
extension Set: CodableWithDefault { ... }
```

you are making `Set` conform to `Codable` without providing the required methods.

In Swift 4.1 you can avoid the implementation of the required methods only if the generic element of Set is `Codable`.

So you need to restrict your extension

```
extension Set: CodableWithDefault where Element : Codable {
    static var `default`: Set {
        return Set()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `Element` `Codable`.To use your extension, you would need to do

```
let set = Set<Yourtype>.defaults
```

Note that there is `Yourtype`. That is what the compiler means by `Element`. Now if you use this code:

```
extension Set: CodableWithDefault where Element: Codable {
    static var defaults: Set {
        return Set()
    }
}
```

the code will compile because `Element` **is** `Encodable` and `Decodable`.